# Break after inline keyword in clang-format

Tags: c++, clang-format

How to make clang-format break after the `inline` keyword in C++?

This is how, e.g., `--style=LLVM` formats `inline`:

```
inline int foo(int a) {
}
```

I'm looking for a way how to make clang-format format the code line this:

```
inline
int foo(int a) {
}
```

It seems I need something similar to `AlwaysBreakTemplateDeclarations: Yes` which does this:

```
template <typename T>
T foo(int a) {
}
```

I can see similar need coming up with a newline after `static`.

Comment: Neither `inline` nor `static` can currently be configured this way, at least as of the latest documentation at https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html.